# cheerio selector for first nested html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, cheerio

This Meteor server side code is trying to get the amount 77 which is in this html string but my selector is returning empty object. How can I get 77 out of this html? Thanks

```js
$('select[name=paid] option').data();
```

```html
<td class="displayValue">

            <select name="paid" id="paidId"><option value="77.00" selected="selected">77.00</option>


              <option value="Other">Other</option></select>

      </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$('select[name=paid] option').first().attr('value')
```

Should work! Your code is too general and won't return anything because there is more than one option.